# How to use relative urls in MSAL's redirectUri?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-ad-msal, azure-static-web-app

In my React app, hosted on Azure as a Static Web App, I use the MSAL library for authentication. In order to create a new Msal.UserAgentApplication, I need to pass a configuration object - which in particular contains the redirectUri. Something like:

```
const msalConfig = {
   auth: {
      clientId: "75d84e7a-40bx-f0a2-91b9-0c82d4c556aa", 
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
      redirectUri: "www.example.org/start",
   },
   ...
```

I'm wondering: **how can I use a relative redirect url, not an absolute one?**

The concrete problem I'm trying to solve is the following one: when I launch and test the app locally, then I want to redirect to *localhost:3000/start* instead of *[www.example.org/start](http://www.example.org/start)*. So far I haven't found any better method than switching the config file before each run/deploy, but it's annoying and of course can be easily forgotten...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it dynamic like this:

```js
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/start'
  }
}
```

This takes the current origin and adds /start to the end.
This way it works locally and in the deployed environment(s).

Comment: The problem is in azure we have to configure redirectUri which it exactly matches with the one we have in our code. So if our local, non-production, production redirect uri's are different how would the azure know which one is valid

Comment: You can configure all the valid URIs in the app registration.